# Login Script does not compare string inputs as expected

Tags: c, string, string-comparison, strcmp

So i want to make a login script and I have coded it but when I run it, it always says "Wrong Username" even though it is right.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MYNAME "SLITHER"  //Defines SLITHER so u can put %s yo use it
#define HackerNum 1338
/*
Welcome To slithers Program
I will be coding what ever I like
c:
*/


void LoginScript ();

char RealUsername[20] = "slither";
char UsersInput[30];

int main ()
{
    printf("Welcome To /bin V1");
    printf("\n Made By slither!\n");

    LoginScript ();
}

void LoginScript ()
{
    printf("Please Login\n");
    printf("Username: ");
    scanf("%s",&UsersInput);
    //printf("You Entered %s", UsersInput); This says what you printed
    if (UsersInput == RealUsername)
    {
        printf("Logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Username");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

- `scanf("%s",&UsersInput);` is undefined behavior due to type mismatch (`char*` expected, got `char (*)[30]`)
- `UsersInput == RealUsername` is comparation of pointers, not contents of strings. `strcmp()` is useful to compare strings.

Add `#include <string.h>` at the beginning of the code and try this:

```
void LoginScript ()
{
    printf("Please Login\n");
    printf("Username: ");
    scanf("%29s",UsersInput); // add 29 (maximum length to read) to avoid buffer overrun
    //printf("You Entered %s", UsersInput); This says what you printed
    if (strcmp(UsersInput, RealUsername) == 0)
    {
        printf("Logged in");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Username");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> *it always says "Wrong Username" even though it is right.*

Yes, that's what it *should*. In your code,

```
  if (UsersInput == RealUsername)
```

is wrong. That's **not** how you should be comparing strings. This statement actually try to compare the pointers themselves, not the "strings" they contain. That's why, your `if` check does not work as they *intend to*.

You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for that (prototyped in `string.h`), like

```
if ( !strcmp(UsersInput, RealUsername) )
{
    printf("Logged in\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Wrong Username\n");
}
```

Having said that,

1. `int main ()` should be `int main (void)` to conform to the standard.
2. `scanf("%s",&UsersInput);` shold better be `scanf("%29s",UsersInput);` to avoid the possible buffer overflow by longer inputs.
3. While initializing an array at the time of definition, it's better to leave the size allocation to the compiler, for example,

   ```
   char RealUsername[ ] = "slither";
   ```

   is considered better over

   ```
   char RealUsername[20] = "slither";
   ```

   At times, it saves the headache of forgetting the count for the size of the terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

Many other including @sourav has given a solution of using strcmp .

I would like to point out why it is always giving "wrong username" as output .

Reason lies in the comparison statement itself .

```
if (UsersInput== RealUsername )
    {
        printf("Logged in");
    }
```

we are not comparing strings here , instead we are comparing their address .And their address will always be different .Hence the result would always be **"wrong username "**